# How to control movement of a person in react three fiber?

Tags: react-three-fiber

I want to create a game where I have to make my model controllable with keyboard input. I don't know what's the best way to do it and how to implement it properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can implement this with cannon.js

1. Create a custom hook to listen to user's input.

```js
const usePersonControls = () => {
  const keys = {
    KeyW: 'forward',
    KeyS: 'backward',
    KeyA: 'left',
    KeyD: 'right',
    Space: 'jump',
  }

  const moveFieldByKey = (key) => keys[key]

  const [movement, setMovement] = useState({
    forward: false,
    backward: false,
    left: false,
    right: false,
    jump: false,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
      setMovement((m) => ({ ...m, [moveFieldByKey(e.code)]: true }))
    }
    const handleKeyUp = (e) => {
      setMovement((m) => ({ ...m, [moveFieldByKey(e.code)]: false }))
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    }
  }, [])
  return movement
}
```

Now use it like so,

```js
const { forward, backward, left, right, jump } = usePersonControls()
```

2. Create a body for person in Cannon World.

```js
const [mesh, api] = useSphere(() => ({
    mass: 10,
    position: [0, 1, 0],
    type: 'Dynamic',
}))
```

3. Apply velocity to sphere body.

```js
useFrame(() => {
    // Calculating front/side movement ...
    let frontVector = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    let sideVector = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    let direction = new Vector3(0,0,0);

    frontVector.set(0, 0, Number(forward) - Number(backward))
    sideVector.set(Number(right) - Number(left), 0, 0)
    direction
      .subVectors(frontVector, sideVector)
      .normalize()
      .multiplyScalar(SPEED)

    api.velocity.set(direction.x, 0, direction.z)
})
```

4. Now our sphere body is able to move with user's input in Cannon World, so now just update your player model in fiber using sphere's position on each frame, like so

```js
// Setting person model position to sphere body position ...
useFrame(() => {
    ...
    mesh.current.getWorldPosition(playerModelReference.current.position)
})
```

Sorry for long explanation, hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more of that last part. Where does playerModelReference come from necessarily?

Comment: Where does frontVector/sideVector/direction get defined?

Answer (score 1):

look here for details on the where does frontVector gets defined
Line 24:9:   'frontVector' is not defined

[How to make character to move around 3D world in React Three Fiber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70429630/how-to-make-character-to-move-around-3d-world-in-react-three-fiber)

```
import React from "react";
import { useSphere } from "@react-three/cannon";
import { useThree, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useKeyboardControls } from "../hooks/useKeyboardControls";
import { Vector3 } from "three";

const SPEED = 6;

export function Person(props) {
    const { camera } = useThree();
    const { moveForward, moveBackward, moveLeft, moveRight } =
        useKeyboardControls();
    const [ref, api] = useSphere(() => ({
        mass: 1,
        type: "Dynamic",
        ...props,
    }));
    const velocity = React.useRef([0, 0, 0]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        api.velocity.subscribe((v) => (velocity.current = v));
    }, [api.velocity]);

    useFrame(() => {
        camera.position.copy(ref.current.position);
        const direction = new Vector3();

        const frontVector = new Vector3(
            0,
            0,
            Number(moveBackward) - Number(moveForward)
        );
        const sideVector = new Vector3(
            Number(moveLeft) - Number(moveRight),
            0,
            0
        );
        direction
            .subVectors(frontVector, sideVector)
            .normalize()
            .multiplyScalar(SPEED)
            .applyEuler(camera.rotation);

        api.velocity.set(direction.x, velocity.current[1], direction.z);
    });

    return (
        <>
            <mesh ref={ref} />
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use KeyboardControls hook from react-three

// App.tsx

```
return <KeyboardControls map={[
            { keys: ["w", "ArrowUp"], name: "moveForward" },
            { keys: ["s", "ArrowDown"], name: "moveBackward" },
            { keys: ["a", "ArrowLeft"], name: "moveLeft" },
            { keys: ["d", "ArrowRight"], name: "moveRight" },
            { keys: ["Space"], name: "jump" }
        ]}>
            <Canvas
                legacy={false}
                shadows
                camera={{
                    position: [10, 10, -10],
                    fov: 30,
                    near: 1,
                    far: 200,
                    zoom: 1,
                }}
            >
              ...

              <Player />

            </Canvas>
</KeyboardControls>
```

and now within Player component you can call the hook to access keyboard events. Below example demo's A ball movement with jump using Rapier physics.

Player.tsx

```
import { useKeyboardControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { RigidBody, useRapier, type RapierRigidBody } from "@react-three/rapier";
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { Vector3 } from "three/src/math/Vector3";

const DOWN_VEC3 = { x: 0, y: -1, z: 0 }
const MAX_TIME_OF_IMPACT = 3
const isSolid = true
const RAY_CAST_ORIGIN = 0.31

const Player = () => {
    const { rapier, world } = useRapier()
    const rapierWorld = world.raw()

    const ref = useRef<RapierRigidBody>(null!)
    const [subscribeKeys, getKeys] = useKeyboardControls()

    const unsub = subscribeKeys((state) => state.jump, (jump) => {
        const origin = ref.current?.translation()
        if (jump && origin) {
            origin.y -= RAY_CAST_ORIGIN;
            const ray = new rapier.Ray(origin, DOWN_VEC3);
            const hit = rapierWorld.castRay(ray, MAX_TIME_OF_IMPACT, isSolid);
            if (hit?.toi < RAY_CAST_ORIGIN) {
                ref.current?.applyImpulse({ x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 0 }, true)
            }
        }
    })

    // Keyboard
    useFrame((state, dt) => {
        const { moveForward, moveBackward, moveLeft, moveRight, jump } = getKeys()

        const impulse = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
        const torque = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }
        const impulseStrength = 0.5 * dt
        const torqueStrength = 0.1 * dt

        if (moveForward) {
            impulse.z += impulseStrength
            torque.x += torqueStrength
        }
        if (moveBackward) {
            impulse.z -= impulseStrength
            torque.x -= torqueStrength
        }
        if (moveLeft) {
            impulse.x += impulseStrength
            torque.z -= torqueStrength
        }
        if (moveRight) {
            impulse.x -= impulseStrength
            torque.z += torqueStrength
        }


        ref.current?.applyImpulse(impulse, true)
        ref.current?.applyTorqueImpulse(torque, true)
    })

    return (
        <RigidBody
            ref={ref}
            position={[0, 1, 0]}
            restitution={0.3}
            friction={0.7}
            linearDamping={0.5}
            angularDamping={0.5}
            colliders="hull"
        >
            <mesh castShadow>
                <icosahedronGeometry args={[0.3, 1]} />
                <meshStandardMaterial flatShading color="limegreen" />
            </mesh>
        </RigidBody>
    );
}

export default Player
```

The player's body is represented by a RigidBody component, which has a mesh of an icosahedron with a green color. The body has properties like position, restitution, friction, linear damping, and angular damping. The colliders property is set to "hull", which means the player's body is represented by a convex hull collider.

When the player presses the jump key, a ray is cast from the bottom of the player's body downwards to check if there is any solid ground below the player. If there is, the player is given an impulse upwards to simulate a jump.

The player's movement is controlled by the keyboard. When the player presses the keys to move forward, backward, left or right, impulses and torques are applied to the player's body to move it in the desired direction.